# RecyclerView inside CoordinatorLayout scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I've got following problem:
My RecyclerView is placed inside the coordinator layout. I am fetching data with pagination and placing it inside RecyclerView. It looks like the CoordinatorLayout triggers scroll (without touching) on RecyclerView what effects in endless fetching more and more data what is followed by OutOfMemory. 
What is more, this happens only if: setNestedScrollingEnabled(false).

Comment: instead of reinventing the wheel using some fancy scroll listeners use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library - first look at `PagedListAdapter`

Comment: I am not paging it on my own. It is twitter's TweetRecyclerViewAdapter, and paging has nothing with that. It is being called after scroll triggered by coordinatorlayout. Outside CoordinatorLayout it works like charm.

Comment: Have you assigned a scroll behavior to the RecyclerView?

Comment: @Wade Wilson Yes, with and without works the same

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what you've done

Comment: Why would a scroll event fetch data endlessly?CoordinatorLayout scroll should be similar to a manual scroll event.